# HDFStore get column names

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, hdfstore

I have some problems with pandas' `HDFStore` being far to slow and unfortunately I'm unable to put together a satisfying solution from other questions here.

#### Situation

I have a big DataFrame, containing mostly floats and sometimes integer columns which goes through multiple processing steps (renaming, removing bad entries, aggregating by 30min). Each row has a timestamp associated to it. I would like to save some middle steps to a HDF file, so that the user can do a single step iteratively without starting from scratch each time.

Additionally the user should be able to plot certain column from these saves in order to select bad data. Therefore I would like to retrieve only the column names without reading the data in the HDFStore.
Concretely the user should get a list of all columns of all dataframes stored in the HDF then they should select which columns they would like to see whereafter I use matplotlib to present them the corresponding data.

Data

`shape == (5730000, 339)` does not seem large at all, that's why I'm confused... (Might get far more rows over time, columns should stay fixed)
In the first step I append iteratively rows and columns (that runs okay), but once that's done I always process the entire DataFrame at once, only grouping or removing data.

#### My approach

1. I do all manipulations in memory since pandas seems to be rather fast and I/O is slower (HDF is on different physical server, I think)
2. I use datetime index and automatically selected float or integer columns
3. I save the steps with `hdf.put('/name', df, format='fixed')` since `hdf.put('/name'.format(grp), df, format='table', data_columns=True)` seemed to be far too slow.
4. I use e.g. `df.groupby(df.index).first()` and `df.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='30Min')).agg(agg_dict)` to process the data, where agg_dict is a dictonary with one function per column. This is incredibly slow as well.
5. For plotting, I have to read-in the entire dataframe and then get the columns: `hdfstore.get('/name').columns`

#### Question

- *How can I retrieve all columns without reading any data from the HDFStore?*
- What would be the most efficient way of storing my data? Is HDF the right option? Table or fixed?
- Does it matter in term of efficiency if the index is a datetime index? Does there exists a more efficient format in general (e.g. all columns the same, fixed dtype?)
- Is there a faster way to aggregate instead of `groupby` (`df.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='30Min')).agg(agg_dict)`)

#### similar questions

[How to access single columns using `.select`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13926089/selecting-columns-from-pandas-hdfstore-table#13977244)
I see that I can use this to retrieve only certain columns but only after I know the column names, I think.

Thank you for any advice!

Comment: Regarding faster way to aggregate: since you have a `DatetimeIndex` have you tried `df.resample('30T').agg(agg_dict)` instead?

Comment: Thanks for the input! It seems to be roughly the same speed, but `.groupby` seems to be more flexible (e.g. I can also use `.apply` instead of `.agg` for more evolved aggregation).

Comment: No problem.  In the latest versions of `pandas` the `.resample()` method when you have a `DatetimeIndex` works more like a `groupby`; you can even do `df.resample().apply()`.  See the [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/api.html#resampling) for more info.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a HDFStore `hdf` and a `key` (from `hdf.keys()`) you can get the column names with:

```
# Table stored with hdf.put(..., format='table')
columns = hdf.get_node('{}/table'.format(key)).description._v_names

# Table stored with hdf.put(..., format='fixed')
columns = list(hdf.get_node('{}/axis0'.format(key)).read().astype(str))
```

note that `hdf.get(key).columns` works as well, but it reads all the data into memory, while the approach above only reads the column names.

---

Full working example:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import pandas as pd

data = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1,1,1,2,3,4,5], 'b': [2,3,4,1,3,2,1]})

with pd.HDFStore(path='store.h5', mode='a') as hdf:
    hdf.put('/DATA/fixed_store', data, format='fixed')
    hdf.put('/DATA/table_store', data, format='table', data_columns=True)
    for key in hdf.keys():
        try:
            # column names of table store
            print(hdf.get_node('{}/table'.format(key)).description._v_names)
        except AttributeError:
            try:
                # column names of fixed store
                print(list(hdf.get_node('{}/axis0'.format(key)).read().astype(str)))
            except AttributeError:
                # e.g. a dataset created by h5py instead of pandas.
                print('unknown node in HDF.')
```

Answer (score 3):

You may simply load 0 rows of the DataFrame by specifying same `start` and `stop` attributes. And leave all internal index/column processing for pandas itself:

```py
idx = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([('A', 'B'), range(2)], names=('Alpha', 'Int'))
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(len(idx), 3), index=idx, columns=('I', 'II', 'III'))
df

>>>                 I           II          III
>>> Alpha   Int             
>>>     A     0     -0.472412    0.436486    0.354592
>>>           1     -0.095776   -0.598585   -0.847514
>>>     B     0      0.107897    1.236039   -0.196927
>>>           1     -0.154014    0.821511    0.092220
```

Following works both for `fixed` an `table` formats:

```py
with pd.HDFStore('test.h5') as store:
    store.put('df', df, format='f')
    meta = store.select('df', start=1, stop=1)
    meta
    meta.index
    meta.columns

>>>               I     II    III
>>> Alpha   Int             
>>>
>>> MultiIndex(levels=[[], []],
>>>            codes=[[], []],
>>>            names=['Alpha', 'Int'])
>>>
>>> Index(['I', 'II', 'III'], dtype='object')
```

As for others question:

1. As long as your data is mostly homogeneous (almost float columns as you mentioned) and you are able to store it in single file without need to distribute data across machines - HDF is the first thing to try.
2. If you need to append/delete/query data - you must use `table` format. If you only need to write once and read many - `fixed` will improve performance.
3. As for datetime index, i think here we may use same idea as in 1 clause. If u are able to convert all data into single type it should increase your performance.
4. Nothing else that proposed in comment to your question comes to mind.

Answer (score 0):

1. Columns without reading any data:

```py
store.get_storer('df').ncols # substitute 'df' with your key
# you can also access nrows and other useful fields
```

2. From the docs ([fixed format](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/io.html#fixed-format), [table format](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/io.html#table-format)): (important points in **bold**)

> [**fixed**] These types of stores are **not appendable** once written (though you can simply remove them and rewrite). **Nor are they queryable**; they must be retrieved in their entirety. They also do not support dataframes with non-unique column names. The fixed format stores offer very fast writing and slightly faster reading than table stores.

> [**table**] Conceptually a table is shaped very much like a DataFrame, with rows and columns. A table **may be appended** to in the same or other sessions. In addition, **delete and query type operations are supported**.

3. You may try to use epochms (or epochns) (milliseconds or nanoseconds since epoch) in place of datetimes. This way, you are just dealing with integer indices.
4. You may have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15798209/pandas-group-by-query-on-large-data-in-hdfstore) if what you need is grouping by on large data.

---

*An advice: if you have 4 questions to ask, it may be better to ask 4 separate questions on SO. This way, you'll get a higher number of (higher quality) answers, since each one is easier to tackle. And each will deal with a specific topic, making it easier to search for people that are looking for specific answers.*